# ensure that scanf only reads dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: c

I am looking for a solution of my problem.
I want to scanf a date (dd.mm.yyyy). I need to make sure, the input is in this format with only 0 < day < 31 ; 0 < month < 13 ; 2018 < year .

For length of the Task, i do it like this:

```
printf("Please typ in the Task: \t");
scanf("%s", &what);
while (strlen(what) >= MAX) {
    clearScanf();
    printf("The task must contain a maximum of %d :\t", MAX - 1);
    scanf("%s", &what);
}
```

But i dont know how to ensure, that my

```
printf("Pls put in the Deadline (dd.mm.yyyy): \t");
scanf("%s", when);
```

wont take characters, but still use the '.' between.

After the scanf, i want to give everything to my structure back with:

```
strcpy(temp->name, what);
strcpy(temp->deadline, when);
temp->next = pointer;
```

But i dont know, how to give month, year and day sepeerat back.

Comment: You can't do that using `scanf` only. You need to parse the string manually, returning errors when you can't parse the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `scanf` + `sscanf`:

```
int day, month, year;
for(;;)                                        /* Infinite loop */
{
    scanf("%s", when);
    char temp;
    if(sscanf(when, "%2d.%2d.%4d%c", &day, &month, &year, &temp) != 4 ||
       temp != '\n')                           /* Check if no extra characters were typed after the date */
    {
        fputs("Invalid format!\n", stderr);
        clearScanf();                          /* Assuming this function of yours clears the stdin */
    }
    else if(!(0 < date && date <= 31) ||       /* Valid range checks */
            !(0 < month && month <= 12) ||
            !(0 < year && year <= 2018))
    {
        fputs("Invalid date!\n", stderr);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

What this does is, it tells `scanf` to first scan a string and then extracts data from it using `sscanf`.

The `sscanf` first extracts 2 digits, then a dot, again two digits, a dot and then 4 digits and finally a character and assigns to the corresponding argument. The character is to check if the user typed more characters.

`sscanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned and assigned. In this case, if it returned 4, it successfully extracted everything.

Comment: Word of warning: `scanf` family is really loose with what it accepts. If I remember correctly, this would also accept date like `3 .  4.-53` (I haven't tested though)

Comment: Although this was my initial thought, this will fail if the user enters, e.g., `19.08.2522`?

Comment: Okay, i need to put the date after that. Right now, i do it like this:
    'strcpy(temp->name, what);
    strcpy(temp->deadline, when);
    strcpy(temp->place, where);
    temp->next = pointer;`

But i cant do it with 3 ints..

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have to put the date after that' ? Do you r

Comment: @user694733 You're right. `scanf` is kinda hard to use correctly, especially for newbies. Your example has a space before the first dot which causes the `scanf` to fail and loop again

Comment: @DavidCollins It does pass when the user enters `19.08.2522`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type `19.08.25253456`. (I.e.,  it doesn't validate the length of the final field.)

Comment: @DavidCollins Yeah, you're right. Amended my answer

Comment: @PascalNo Changed my answer.

Comment: Might as well use `fgets` rather than `scanf` now, especially as that'll protect from buffer overflow

Comment: @CoolGuy this doesnt work fo rme tbh.. If i typ in 02.02.2018, it still tells me Invalid format. I changed one line to !(year >=2018) beacuse i need all dates from 01.01.2018 onwards

Answer (score 0):

Write your own format checking function:

```
bool is_correctly_formatted(const char* s) {

    if(!isdigit(s[0])) return false;
    if(!isdigit(s[1])) return false;
    if('.' != s[2]) return false;
    if(!isdigit(s[3])) return false;
    if(!isdigit(s[4])) return false;
    if('.' != s[5]) return false;
    if(!isdigit(s[6])) return false;
    if(!isdigit(s[7])) return false;
    if(0 != s[8]) return false;

    return true;

}
```

You can then use it like:

```
#define MAX 8

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* Space for MAX chars + line feed + terminal zero */
    char what[MAX + 1 + 1] = {0};

    /* Ensure that scanf reads in at most as many chars as can be safely written to `what` */
    char format[MAX + 2 + 1] = {0};
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", MAX + 1);

    do {
        printf("%s Please type in the Task: ", format);
        scanf(format, &what[0]);
        /* chomp the trailing '\n' */
        if(isspace(what[MAX + 1])) what[MAX + 1] = 0;
        printf("Entered %s\n", what);
    } while (! is_correctly_formatted(what));
}
```

This enables you to be as flexible in what you expect as possible. You could even resort back to using some kind of [regex library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Beware: The read string will contain the trailing line feed, thus you got to remove it...